# Ansible: apt - format of commands

Tags: ansible, apt

These Ansible tasks seem different:

```
  - name: Ensure Nginx is installed
    apt: name=nginx update_cache=yes
```

and

```
 - name: Install Nginx
     apt: pkg=nginx state=installed update_cache=true
```

but looking at http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/apt_module.html I see:

`pkg` is an alias of `name` so can ignore

However, what about:

1. `update_cache=true` - this doesn't seem to be valid in the 2nd example. Is that correct?
2. the first example is missing a `state=installed`. However, it does seem to work when I run it. Why's that?

Answer (score 0):

1. `true` and `yes` are interchangeable so both examples are correct.  Same goes for `false` and `no`.
2. The default value for `state` is `present` so an equivalent task to the first example would be `apt: pkg=nginx state=present update_cache=yes`. The ansible docs don't mention the `installed` state but it looks like that's an alias for `present`.